# DWH and ETL explained

Tags: etl, dimensional-modeling

In this post I am not asking any tutorials, how to do something, in this post, I am asking your help, if someone could explain me with simple words, what is DWH (data warehouse ) and what is ETL.

Of course,  I google'ed and youtube'd alot, I found many articles, videos, but still, I am not very sure what it is.

Why I am asking?
I need to know it very well before I am applying for a job.

Comment: Just right now I am watching videos about that, and most important is Data warehouse, how it works, what it is, when it's used.

As I understand, ( if that's correct )

DWH is mostly used to analyze  data, to group it, so when we search for some sort of data, we no need to go thru ALL database, because it's nicely sorted in a DWH.
It's easier and faster to find what we need. ?

Comment: So I just want to be sure, if  the part I think I understand know, if its correct.
so lets say we got a company that uses DWH, lets say there is  sales, marketing, finances and so on.. each part of this company contains information ( data ) which is needed to analyze.
So all the data, that comes from marketing,finances or sales goes to integration level, where is ETL part happening.
E - data comes to this part, T - we transform data to format we need, L- we load it to DWH.
Then all date is sorted by parts, Sale data, marketing data, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>This answer by no means should be treated as a complete definition of a data warehouse. It's only my attempt to explain the term in layman's terms.</sub>

Transactional (operational, OLTP) and analytical (data warehouses) systems can both use the same RDBMS as the back-end and they may contain exactly the same data. However, their **data models will be completely different**, because they are **optimized for different access patterns**.

In transactional systems you usually work with a single row (e.g. a customer or an invoice) and the write consistency is crucial, so the data model is normalized. On the contrary, data warehouses are optimized for reading large number of rows (e.g. all invoices from the previous year) and aggregating data, so dimensional models are flattened (star schema, Kimball's dimensions and facts).

Transactional systems store only the current version of entities (i.e. current customer's address), while data warehouses may use slowly changing dimensions (SCD) to preserve history (e.g. all addresses of the customer with date ranges to indicate when each of them was valid).

ETL stands for *extract, transform, load* and it is the procedure of:

1. extracting data from a transactional system,
2. transforming it into dimensional format,
3. loading in a data warehouse.

Comment: I would just add that ETL = Extraction, Transformation, Loading